# Private node cannot join cluster

Tags: networking, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I've been trying to create a EKS cluster in terraform, the scripts below works fine if I create my worker nodes in hte public subnet. However if i try to put them in the private subnet, it fails for `unable to join cluster`.

I think it's something to do with the gateway, but I've tried a lot of things now and i just can't to see what the issue is, would someone be able to help me please.

https://gitlab.com/roboops/case_study/-/tree/master/terraform

Answer (score 0):

As per EKS documentation you would need outbound access for internet for worker nodes.

Check the notes section here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html